# Converting a range of integers from a string to an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, strings, converting, integer, interval

**Goal**

Convert the following into an `IEnumerable` of integers accounting for the `x-y` ranges:

> ```
> "1,2,3,0,7,8,9,10-15"
> ```

to

> ```
> { 1, 2, 3, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
> ```

**Current implementation**

I've written this [little function](https://gist.github.com/1282930) and got something working, but I'm wondering if this can become more efficient or rich in features. My test cases all pass which cover positive and negative ranges.

```c#
public IEnumerable<int> GetRange(string numbers) {
    string[] items = numbers.Split(',');

    foreach (var item in items) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)) {
            //does it contain a -? it's a range then
            int result;
            if (item.Contains("-") && !item.EndsWith("-")) {
                int start, end;
                if (int.TryParse(item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf("-")), out start) && int.TryParse(item.Substring(item.IndexOf("-") + 1), out end)) {
                    int direction = start < end ? 1 : -1;
                    for (result = start; (direction == 1 ? result < end + direction : result > end + direction); result += direction)
                        yield return result;

                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (int.TryParse(item, out result)) {
                yield return result;
                continue;
            }

        }

        throw new InvalidCastException(string.Format("Unable to cast \"{0}\" to an int", item));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can there be more than one range? Are non-ranged items sequential?

Comment: the ranged items are sequential, by default

Answer (score 6):

Ok, some comments:

- Code style

  - While there are no definitive laws about code style, most C# programmers are putting the opening brace `{` on a separate line. If someone else is going to read your code, they are likely to be annoyed.
  - Consider breaking up the method into smaller methods to clarify how it works, which is better than adding comments.
- Nesting, minimizing nesting makes the code easier to read and in this case you can certainly remove a few levels, namely:

  - `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))` can be removed if you instead split the string with the parameter `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.
  - If the number cannot be parsed, you could throw the exception when `TryParse` returns false and keep the "happy path" code to run whenever `TryParse` is successful.
- Error handling

  - Since it is `TryParse` that is failing, you should probably throw a `FormatException` to indicate invalid format or `ArgumentException` instead of `InvalidCastException` to indicate invalid input parameter. Since there is no casting that is failing within the code, this may confuse other developers when debugging the code.
  - Stricter validation of input data, for example, to handle the case with the method being invoked with the numbers parameter set to `null`.
- Performance

  - There is always things to improve in this department, however, if the method is fast enough for you, I suggest focusing on readability.
- Defect

  - Invoking the method with a negative range where the first number is negative will not work.